# Accessing calendar on an asp.net userControl by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, calendar

I'm working on an ASP.NET app

I'm using a UserControl for a year calendar.
This UserControl has 12 asp.net calendar controls (for the 12 months of a year)

I'm trying to build a jscript function that can access to one (or more) of the 12 month calendar, but I can't access them.

example:

```
"<asp:Calendar ID="CalendarJanuary" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>"
```

here's my function

```
function SetCalendar(controlId) {

  document.getElementById(controlId+'_CalendarJanuary').VisibleDate = somedate    
}
```

but this is allways throwing an error:
'Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object'

it seems is not finding the calendar and I'm sure i'm passing the right controlID

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's actually possible to access the server control properties from JavaScript. First of all, you can get a valid object by calling this line of JavaScript:

```
var control = document.getElementById("<%=CalendarJanuary.ClientID%>");
```

But this won't actually give you access to the ASP properties.

What you *can* do, is add a hidden input field to your form where you will store the new selection, which you set using JavaScript. Then on postback you could update your calendar with that value.